# merge tables using r with mysql

Tags: mysql, r

There's a table in MySql server, like

```
    (TABLE NAME: MAIN)
    id    name    attr    ...    jedi    color
    ------------------------------------------
    1     one     alpha   ...    NA      NA
    2     two     beta    ...    NA      NA
    3     three   gamma   ...    NA      NA
    ...   ...     ...     ...    ...     ...
```

and another table in my local storage,

```
    (TABLE NAME: SUB)
    id    jedi     color
    ---------------------
    2     obi-wan  blue
    1     windu    purple
    3     luke     green
    ...   ...      ...
```

I want to merge these tables by id, and save the result to MySql table at the same time. The 'MAIN' table has many foreign keys, so i don't want to delete or change anything in that table, just want to add that 'SUB' data into 'MAIN' table. How can i do that?

Comment: what you have tried so far. Where is your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use an update join here:

```
UPDATE MAIN m
INNER JOIN SUB s
    ON m.id = s.id
SET m.jedi = s.jedi AND m.color = s.color;
```

This assumes that the `SUB` table is already in MySQL is some way.  An easy option would be to just create `SUB` as a temporary table, used just to do the update.

Of course, if you are working in R then you are probably using some API (you never mentioned which one), which could help here.